# Find differences in a UTF-8 string by character code in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, diff

I need to find the differences between Hebrew (read from right to left) sentences such as

בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
(with cantillation marks) and

בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃
(without cantillation marks).

It may not look very different to you but a Hebrew reader will be able to see the cantillation marks in the first phrase.

It might also be the case that the extra little dots (vowels) are not always the same in the two texts.

So I need a way of checking the UTF-8 encoded texts in PHP and highlighting the differences in some way, so that I can say to someone on the first word underneath the 'Shin' you are missing the 05AD unicode character 'Dehi'.

Comment: Well - isn't it then just comparing the strings and highlight the difference? 
I don't think I get what you're actually asking for?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The question is how do I extract those differences on a UTF-8 character for character basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str1 = 'בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃';
$str2 = 'בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ';

$len1 = mb_strlen($str1, 'utf-8');
for($i = 0, $arr1 = array(); $i < $len1; $i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($str1, $i, 1, 'utf-8');
    if (preg_match('/[\x{0591}-\x{05c7}]/u', $char)) {
        end($arr1);
        $key = key($arr1);
        $arr1[$key] = $arr1[$key] . $char;
    } else if (preg_match('/\p{Zs}/u', $char)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $arr1[$i] = $char;
    }
}
ksort($arr1);
$arr1 = array_values($arr1);

$len2 = mb_strlen($str2, 'utf-8');
for($i = 0, $arr2 = array(); $i < $len2; $i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($str2, $i, 1, 'utf-8');
    if (preg_match('/[\x{0591}-\x{05c7}]/u', $char)) {
        end($arr2);
        $key = key($arr2);
        $arr2[$key] = $arr2[$key] . $char;
    } else if (preg_match('/\p{Zs}/u', $char)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $arr2[$i] = $char;
    }
}
ksort($arr2);
$arr2 = array_values($arr2);

$results = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != $arr2[$key]) {
        $results[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

I got it, and the results shows

```
array (size=8)
  3 => string 'שִׁ֖' (length=8)
  7 => string 'רָ֣' (length=6)
  11 => string 'הִ֑' (length=6)
  14 => string 'אֵ֥' (length=6)
  18 => string 'מַ֖' (length=6)
  22 => string 'אֵ֥' (length=6)
  25 => string 'אָֽ' (length=6)
  27 => string 'ץ׃' (length=4)
```

the 3, 7, 11, 14, 18, 22, 25, 27th character is different (count from right to left, and from 0);

Comment: This is probably due to these little extra cantillation marks I've mentioned in the question. They ought to look a little different upon close examination.

Comment: so 2 cantillation marks + 1 normal character = 1 Hebrew character?

Comment: There are basically three components to the letters of the texts above. The actual letter, the extra dots and dashes (vowels) found in both the phrases above. And the cantillation marks found only in the top phrase. A fluent Hebrew speaker would really only need the letters to read it, but the other two components are there to facilitate accurate reading and help the reader along where necessary.

Comment: So yes each letter as you see it there in the question might actually be two or three Unicode characters.

Comment: ok, let me restart pc first, I can't open my hex editor :) btw, Im not character set pro, but I know little, let me find if I can help you

Comment: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1280 what unicode range is the actual letters? U+05D0 to U+05EA?